# What triggers crew experience increases?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When I've got a station manned, I'm trying to work out what causes my crew to develop in skills. It looks like engines and cockpit crew only upgrade when an attack is dodged, and then get a single skill point. Is this correct, and what causes Shields and Weapons to get an upgrade point?

Comment: As of the 'advanced edition' update, the game shows you (in the crew panel) when anyone gains an atom of experience, so it's much more obvious.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

#### Piloting

A crew member who is controlling a helm gains one point of experience for each incoming projectile that is dodged during combat.  This includes asteroids, so long as you are in combat at the time.  (Note that the dodges do not count while you ship is under the effects of +60% evasion from a cloak.)

This can be explicitly trained by finding an enemy that cannot break through your shields, and letting him fire at you.  Increasing your dodge chance (i.e. more power to engines) will help this occur quicker, but even with the default chance you can max out the skill eventually.

#### Engines

Exactly as for piloting, a crew member manning the engines gains one point of XP for each projectile evaded while uncloaked in combat - and so it can be trained in the same way.

#### Weapons

A crew member who is manning the weapons station gains one point of experience for each weapon that is fired.  It doesn't matter whether it hits or misses, or whether it can do damage (e.g. a beam weapon fired at a shield).

(Multi-shot weapons such as burst lasers still count as a single fire order and hence a single XP.)

This can be trained by firing non-lethal weapons (e.g. ones that do ion damage) repeatedly against a target that cannot damage you.

#### Shields

A crew member manning the shields station gains one point of experience for each shield "bubble" that is brought back up during combat.  It doesn't matter why the shields were down, be that direct enemy fire, ion damage, asteroid strikes, <strike>or even manually removing and then restoring power to the shield systems</strike>.

This can be trained by letting a target that cannot break through all of your shields repeatedly take one layer down. (For fastest results, move your pilot away from the helm, or reduce your engines to 0 power.  This will reduce your dodge chance to 0%, ensuring that everything hits your shields.)

Note that you used to be able to manually remove power and restore it in combat, to get points, but this has been patched.

#### Repair

A crew member gains one point of experience for getting the "finishing blow" when repairing a (sub)system.  Note that hull breaches provide no repair experience.

There's no specific way to train this as it requires your systems to be damaged.  Though you can focus the XP gains by always having the same person run around and repair everything after a battle.

#### Combat

A crew member gains one point of experience for getting the finishing blow when fighting an enemy crew member *or (sub)system*.

This generally gets trained in "real" situations.  However, since XP is gained for taking out systems, a few extra XP can be gained from boarding if one tries to take out the enemy's systems before the crew.

Comment: a tip for repair, some weapons allow for self ship targeting so you can train your crew if you can damage your own ship subsystems.  Usually, I let my ship catch on fire if its the end of a fight (no more enemies) and then repair all the damage to boost repair.

Comment: I considered adding that - but don't you take hull damage when a system gets damaged by fire?  It's not worth trading one hull damage for one repair XP, so unless there is a riskless way to damage your own systems it's a non-starter.

Comment: true, I forgot about that part, I don't think you take hull damage every time, its a random chance

Comment: Brilliant comprehensive answer, especially that tip regarding shields.

Comment: you take one hull damage every time a system goes red, no matter the cause.

Comment: Hint: the Engi Cruiser Type A's Ion Cannon charges in four seconds, so a gunner who mans this will level up quickly.

Comment: Through the careful use of deoxygenated rooms to contain and starve fires, you can keep a fire alive in an empty room or one where the system is already fully damaged (surrounded by oxygenless rooms. You can allow the fire to spread to a room with an undamaged system (preferably one with a lot of power capacity to prevent hull damage), then put out the fire (rockmen or oxygen) before the system goes into the red. Repair the system to full and repeat as necessary. The success of this technique depends on the ship and how you manage it.

Comment: Bonus trick - since Piloting and Engines trigger on the same thing (dodging incoming), a maxed out Pilot can help an Engineer gain skill points by increasing the dodge chance. (And vice versa).

Comment: A small, seldom available way to improve repair training is to upgrade a damaged subsystem. The additional bar will be damaged too, allowing for 1 extra repair.

Comment: Another option to boost repair is to fight a ship with beams that don't pass your shield and bomb-type weapons. It'll eventually run out of missiles, but you get a lot repair exp without paying for the missiles yourself. These specific ships can be kind of rare though...

Answer (score 8):

Advanced Edition:

Asteroid fields used to be an excellent way to max out the shield stat on one or more characters, however, with the advanced edition, this is no longer possible.  Even in combat, shield damage from asteroids no longer provide any benefit.  Thus, if you want to raise the shield stat, you are best off letting an enemy incapable of breaking through all of your shields repeatedly hit you.

A trick regarding hand-to-hand combat is now to board an enemy vessel that has a cloning bay and repeatedly kill off the crew in melee combat.  As long as you don't destroy the cloning bay while all of their crew is dead, they will continue to re-spawn -- allowing you to maximize the combat stat on as many of your crew-mates as you'd like if you are careful.

Comment: For combat, another option (if you have a sufficiently good teleporter to avoid asphyxiation) is to repeatedly beam your crew onto an unmanned enemy ship and have them attack all its systems until it only has 1 hp left.

Comment: Training Combat Skill by fighting clones does *not* work. Just tried exactly that, but my crew did not earn XP.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that is correct.

Shield operators get a point for every shield bubble they help to bring up in combat.

Weapon operators get a point for every weapon they help fire. This is per target action, so a single burst of 5 shots from a Burst Laser 3 will only provide 1 experience (but could provide multiple experience in shield, pilot, or engines to a target crew).

Answer (score 2):

Just found out this one by accident.
Went against a drone that could not get past my shields. It had a mind control module on it.

Your hull does not take damage if the system isn't broken completely. So just put your men in rooms with more than 2 power in them. Let them break one power on it (not shieds preferrably), and as he comes out of the mind control, he will repair the room getting skillup in repair.
Gives you XP during the mind control for breaking the room and XP in repairs as he repairs it.