# What are the benefits of upgrading crew in FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

There's a little skill meter next to every skill for each crew member.

[image: Mad skills!!!]

They naturally increase in the skills they use. But what are the benefits of increased skill levels?

I'm looking for hard numbers, eg. If I have a pilot with 50% piloting experience, how does that affect my dodge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Crew members gain experience whenever the subsystem they're manning gets used (for more detail see: [What triggers crew experience increases?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85179/what-triggers-crew-experience-increases)). The experience itself does not do anything - it is when the crew gains a skill level when the exp bar is full that they you gain additional bonus when the crew mans the subsystem he is skilled in.

- Piloting: +5/7/10% Evasion in Piloting
- Engines: +5/7/10% Evasion in Engines
- Shields: +10/20/29% Shield recharge rate
- Weapons: +10/14/19% Weapons charge rate
- Repair: Faster repair speed
- Combat: -/+10%/+20% damage

Taken from the [FTL wiki article on skills](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Skills)